# What's the Pythonic way to implement "diamond inheritance"?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm facing a nearly-textbook diamond inheritance problem.  The (rather artificial!) example below captures all its essential features:

```
# CAVEAT: error-checking omitted for simplicity

class top(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix  # matrix must be non-empty and rectangular!

    def foo(self):
        '''Sum all matrix entries.'''
        return sum([sum(row) for row in self.matrix])

class middle_0(top):
    def foo(self):
        '''Sum all matrix entries along (wrap-around) diagonal.'''
        matrix = self.matrix
        n = len(matrix[0])
        return sum([row[i % n] for i, row in enumerate(matrix)])

class middle_1(top):
    def __init__(self, m, n):
        data = range(m * n)
        matrix = [[1 + data[i * n + j] for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]

        super(middle_1, self).__init__(matrix)
```

In summary, classes `middle_0` and `middle_1` are both subclasses of class `top`, where `middle_0` overrides method `foo` and `middle_1` overrides method `__init__`.  Basically, the classic diamond inheritance set up.  The one elaboration on the basic pattern is that `middle_1.__init__` actually invokes the parent class's `__init__`.  (The demo below shows these classes in action.)

I want to define a class `bottom` that "gets"<sup>1</sup> `foo` from `middle_0` and `__init__` from `middle_1`.

What's the "pythonic way" to implement such a `bottom` class?

---

Demo:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print top(matrix).foo()
# 45
print middle_0(matrix).foo()
# 15
print middle_1(3, 3).foo()
# 45

# print bottom(3, 3).foo()
# 15
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>I write "gets" instead of "inherits" because I suspect this problem can't be solved easily using standard Python inheritance.</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: A blog that can possibly explain the multiple inheritance order to you: http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bottom` simply inherits from both; there is nothing specific about your classes that would make this case special:

```
class bottom(middle_0, middle_1):
    pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> class bottom(middle_0, middle_1):
...     pass
... 
>>> bottom(3, 3).foo()
15
```

This works as expected because Python arranges both `middle_0` and `middle_1` to be searched for methods before `top` is:

```
>>> bottom.__mro__
(<class '__main__.bottom'>, <class '__main__.middle_0'>, <class '__main__.middle_1'>, <class '__main__.top'>, <type 'object'>)
```

This shows the *Method Resolution Order* of the class; it is that order that is used to find methods. So `bottom.__init__` is found on `middle_1`, and `bottom.foo` is found on `middle_0`, as both are listed before `top`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I must conclude that my example is somehow missing the feature of my actual problem that caused this solution to fail when I tried it (and prompted me to post the question).  The code I'm working with is pretty large/complicated, so posting it would be impractical...  I must investigate further.

Comment: @kjo the same principles apply; you need to look at the MRO to see where a method will be found.

Answer (score 2):

I think the

> a class bottom that "gets"1 foo from middle_0 and __init__ from middle_1.

would be simply done by

```
class bottom(middle_0, middle_1):
    pass
```